# Can it be accurate to say that time is also a length?

Tags: spacetime, time, dimensional-analysis, length

So a type of measurement, in units, is length, position, mass, etc, and a unit is meters, kilograms, etc.
Is it accurate to say that "an hour" is a time measurement, but also a form of length, especially if we're talking about time "*passing*"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_interval

Comment: Physicists are comfortable measuring durations in meters rather than seconds, or lengths in seconds rather than meters. They routinely set $c=1$ to keep things simple, so 1 second = 299,792,458 meters.

Answer (score 4):

The “type of measurement” is called the measurement’s dimensionality. Both the size of a unit and its dimensionality is a matter of convention which is determined by the system of units that is being used. This is often surprising to people who often think that the dimensionality of a quantity is determined by nature rather than by convention.

The [SI units in Section 2.3.3](https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=927835) define time and length to have different dimensions. However, the [geometrized units](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system) define time and length to have the same dimensionality. So it really is just a matter of which convention you would like to choose. You can use whichever is more convenient or helpful for a given situation

Answer (score 2):

In a technical sense, you can use a system of units where time has the same units as length. This makes sense to do if there is a special *speed* that is relevant to your problem. For example, in relativity, the speed of light is a special quantity. Then you could say a given length of time is "3 meters", which would refer to the amount of time it takes light to travel 3 meters.

Having said that, the standard SI system of units do use different dimensions for lengths and time intervals. For scientists who do not work on relativity, it is much more common to use different units for space and time.

However, as you know from your daily experience, even if they can be measured in the same units, time and space are not *equivalent*. For example, it is possible to move forward and backward along an axis in space, but it is only possible to move in one direction along the time axis. So, it is important not to over-interpret the technical sense in which these quantities can be measured in the same units, as a full mathematical equivalence.

Comment: Ok so, if I understand correctly, time can be measured as length, but it actually is dependent rather on the purpose rather than something else. Because essentially in one equation it would become relevant to equate time with length, but in some others, not at all. Right?

Comment: @FMB Let me make an analogy. It turns out that torque and work have the same units (${\rm N \cdot m}$). However, work and torque are not *equivalent*. They describe different physical concepts. Similarly, while time and space can be measured in the same units, they are physically distinct concepts. I think the fact there is an arrow of time (there is a distinction between past and future), but not an arrow of space (there is no distinction between right and left), is a clear manifestation of this.

Answer (score 1):

Time absolutely can be conceptualized as a unit of “length.” But it is critically important that you recognize time has a different unit than distance. In the field of relativity, time and space are put on equal footing and we deal with various forms of “spacetime.” In this regard, it makes just as much sense to worry about how far away events are in time as they are in space, as the relative motion of the two will cause apparent geometric changes in the size of objects along their various spatial and temporal axes (length contraction and time dilation). I won’t get into technical details since they are not directly related to your question, but you essentially just hinted at why relativity is tricky to conceptualize. In fact, in the field of relativity you often see the “time axis” treated in terms of $ct$ rather than just $t$, as this gives the time axis units of distance! You have to think about space and time simultaneously as a single United entity rather than separate things.